# ServiceStack Auth ProviderOAuthAccess

Tags: .net, servicestack, identityserver4

What can be the reason that in this method:

```
public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, 
                                    IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
```

Inside `session` I have in one case `ProviderOAuthAccess` count 1 when I try it on my local auth server instance (http://localhost:5001), and when I deploy the same application on https://my-deployed-instance.azurewebsites.net/ I got count 0.

Note, my client application run on localhost on regular (non ssl) port. Not sure if that's somehow related or not, but as I said, with same auth provider that I use on localhost I'm getting proper behavior, but when I try to to connect my app to use it from azure, it does not work properly.

I am able to receive callbacks etc. but something is off with this session.

Answer (score 0):

This question can essentially be rephrased to:

> “My Auth Provider doesn’t work when run on Azure”

The `Authenticate()` method is the implementation for the Auth Provider that when successful will be populated in `AuthUserSession.ProviderOAuthAccess`. So it’s not working, but your post doesn’t include any info into why it’s not working which is ultimately down to the custom Auth Provider implementation you’re using. A common behaviour most Auth Providers use to indicate that it’s failed is to redirect to a `#f=XXXX` fragment containing the Error Code at which point its failed whereas successful OAuth attempts redirects usually contain `#s=1`.

Comment: The only difference that I was able to find was in fiddler related to cookies. When I test the full workflow in local host I do have these `ss-` cookies + cookies from IdentityServer4. However, when I'm using IdentityServer4 on azure, I get 2 `ss-` cookies set, then request goes to IDSvr, and then, these two `ss` cookies are no longer there when I got redirected back to localhost... + these additional IDSVR cookies are missing (but that's fine I guess since it's for different domain).

Comment: is there some other out of the box solution where these sessions can be stored instead of using cookies.

Comment: @ShP Sessions are stored in the servers cache client, Cookies are only used to reference Sessions. I’m not familiar with this Auth Provider but if ProviderOAuthAccess is empty it suggests it wasn’t populated and the Auth flow didn’t work.

Comment: check this print-screen http://prntscr.com/lcgz6i this is where it got added and this is next request http://prntscr.com/lcgzts

Comment: Also is the normal behavior for cookie to disappear after 302 (redirect) from one domain to another and back to original domain, if that is normal behavior, then if cookie is gone we lose the reference to session, right?

Answer (score 0):

@Shp if the Cookies are gone then references to the Session is lost. It’s not normal to lose Cookies after a redirect, they remain for the domain/path they were assigned to until they expire (or are deleted, which is done by setting an expiry date in the past). Temp Cookies (aka Session Cookies) last until the browser is open whilst permanent Cookies last beyond browser restarts until their expiry date (or they’re manually cleared).

Comment: That was my understanding as well, that they should remain until they are removed or expired, but somehow they got lost after redirecting to another domain and I have no idea why or how because there's nothing in code that removes them as well. Interesting part is that they are staying set when there's a redirection on localhost but on other port (local version of identity server).

Comment: @ShP you'd need to inspect the HTTP traffic to find out what's going on, browsers don't care about implementations or redirects, they have pre-set rules to send active cookies when making requests to the same domain/path they were assigned to.